# acf is breaking mobile menu on iphone

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, advanced-custom-fields

On this site, on my iphone only (but not responsive view or emulators) my mobile hamburger menu is broken if ACF plugin is activated

https://beechers.darkstarmedia.net/

I have tested this extensively, the problem is 100% the ACF plugin. Is there some sort of jquery conflict with the plugin?

it works on my apple PC safari, chrome, firefox, regular and responsive mode. iPhone Simulator, Andriod studio.. just not an iphone

Comment: With zero additional information there is really no way to tell. Is the mobile menu a custom script? is it a plugin? generally you can see js issues in the console. etc.

Comment: no console errors, basic boostrap nav walker menu i have used 100s of times

Comment: also discovered that chrome and firefox on iphone have same issue, and  the pages never finish loading

Comment: Are you able to enable ACF so it can be checked?

Comment: it is enabled now

Comment: go ahead and turn it back off.

Comment: it is now off, i am also updating my OS, it is only 1 update off, but lets see.. i was 15.2, updating to 15.3.1

Comment: installing ACF pro for a minute to see if that makes a difference

Comment: didn't help with pro version, it is back off

Comment: with the footer not loading, its hard to tell since there are no actual ACF scripts loading. Can you fix it so it doesn't error out and the footer loads? I'm assuming you aren't checking if ACF is loaded and just pulling from the fields directly which will cause that issue.

Comment: I commented out the fields (on home page only), footer loads now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running 2 versions of jQuery.

[image]

Try removing your manually added 3.3.1 or set WordPress not to load the 3.6.0 min.js .

Looks like rocket-loader isn't seeing jQuery. I'm assuming its the Cloudflare plugin? if so, could try disabling it. –

Comment: this is done, i can't get the page to finish loading at all now

Comment: you may need to dequeue the default version since you are using what appears to be the bootstrap 4.0.0 version

Comment: now i am getting cloudflare rocket loader console errors

Comment: This clearly shows the issue isn't ACF though. Its a JS issue.

Comment: agreed, putting cloudflare in dev mode doesn't make error go away

Comment: Looks like rocket-loader isn't seeing jQuery. I'm assuming its the Cloudflare plugin? if so, could try disabling it.

Comment: that's the issue, Cloudflare rocket loader.. now it is disabled, everything works. Thank you for going through that with me

Comment: this was what helped us troubleshoot, I can't mark it as the answer though "with the footer not loading, its hard to tell since there are no actual ACF scripts loading. Can you fix it so it doesn't error out and the footer loads? I'm assuming you aren't checking if ACF is loaded and just pulling from the fields directly which will cause that issue"

Comment: Updated the answer to include that as well.